# Conditionally include/exclude a field from being searched

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We have a really wide index that we used for site-wide search of multiple pieces of content. I'd like to add a new field that only admins can search -- normal users shouldn't be able to search on it.

Currently, it looks like the only way to blacklist a search field is to use [`SearchParamaters.SearchFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn947047.aspx), but this would require listing every single other field, which is not ideal, as our index grows occasionally, and would require remembering to add to this list.

Alternatively, we could use reflection to build this list, and we may go this route if it's our only option. Was just hoping there was another option I was overlooking.

Comment: Normally security trimmng applies to documents, not fields. Can you share more about your scenario? In particular, why is it necessary to prevent matching on certain fields as opposed to just not having such fields present in the search response?

Comment: Say we have a User document, but that document may contain sensitive data that isn't retrievable, but admins can do lookups using the sensitive data. For example, email address.

Comment: Since the field is not retrievable, there is no risk of data disclosure, right? At worst a user might get search hits and not understand why.

Other than using searchFields, another way to deal with this would be to build a second index for admin searches that contains all the sensitive fields, where each document contains a reference back to the ID of the end-user-visible document.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't ideal, I ended up creating `[Searchable]` and `[AdminSearchable]`  attributes, and decorated these on all the properties of our search document class:

```
[Searchable]
public string UserName { get; set; }

[Searchable]
public string UserDisplay { get; set; }

[AdminSearchable]
public string UserEmail { get; set; }
```

And then used these `static` fields to build the list of searchable fields, based on whether or not the current user is an admin:

```
private static readonly string[] _PublicSearchFeilds = 
    typeof(SearchDocument).GetProperties()
    .Where(p => System.Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(SearchableAttribute)))
    .Select(p => p.Name.ToLowerCamelCase()).ToArray();

private static readonly string[] _AdminSearchFeilds = 
    typeof(SearchDocument).GetProperties()
    .Where(p => 
        System.Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(SearchableAttribute)) ||
        System.Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(AdminSearchableAttribute)))
    .Select(p => p.Name.ToLowerCamelCase()).ToArray();
```

And passed this into `SearchParameters.SearchFields`.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to specify a list of fields to exclude from searches. Feel free to add this as a feature request on [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/filters/top) to help us prioritize.

Comment: Thanks, Bruce. I came up with a workable solution. The only thing I don't like about my solution is that I have to explicitly define each public/admin searchable field. But it gets the job done, and allows us to use the same index.